# Instruments crashes app with Hardened Runtime on macOS Mojave

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-mojave, codesign, xcode-instruments

I found that Xcode 10 Instruments (Leaks) would fail to attach to a command-line application signed with [Hardened Runtime](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/hardened_runtime_entitlements?language=objc) enabled, with the following error:

> Error: Failed to attach to target process

I added the **com.apple.security.get-task-allow** entitlement to the application, and re-signed it. Then, instead of failing to attach, the application would crash with signal 9. When the application crashed, the following was logged to Console.app:

> CODE SIGNING: process 93890[appname]: rejecting invalid page at address 0x1015f9000 from offset 0x0 in file "" (cs_mtime:0.0 == mtime:0.0) (signed:0 validated:0 tainted:0 nx:0 wpmapped:1 dirty:0 depth:0)

How do attach Instruments to this application? I am running macOS Mojave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two ways to fix this:

1. Do not codesign with Hardened Runtime enabled - this is a good solution for debug builds, but not for a release build that you might want to [notarize](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_your_app_before_distribution). Additionally, it misses out on the security protections provided by Hardened Runtime.
2. Add another entitlement: **[com.apple.security.cs.disable-executable-page-protection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_security_cs_disable-executable-page-protection?language=objc)**. This works, but it concerns me that it is required. It also impacts security, but less so than the first solution.

Comment: could you please elaborate on point 1, since Hardened Runtime is required by notarization!

Comment: What I mean in point 1 is signing without Hardened Runtime, and also not notarizing the build. This is of course not suitable for builds you are going to release.